# JAVA Returning the parent object - Inheritance from inheritance - Builder Pattern

Tags: java, parent-child, builder, extends, return-type

I'm sure this issue might have already been answered but after looking around, I'm not sure of the correct terminology to get me a solid answer. Either this, or I'm not fully understanding something.

I'm trying to create a selection of builders that have varying methods, however, they must all inherit from the "base" builder. This is fine, but I can't get it to return the right object to continue the builder pattern.

An example of what I've tried:

```
public class Builder1 {
    protected String string = new String();

    public <T extends Builder1 > T append1(String string) {
        this.string += string;
        return (T)this;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.string);
    }

}
```

```
public class Builder2 extends Builder1 {

    public <T extends builder2 > T append2(String string) {
        this.string += string;
        return (T)this;
    }

}
```

```
public class Builder3 extends Builder2 {

    public <T extends Builder3 > T append3(String string) {
        this.string += string;
        return (T)this;
    }

}
```

So, if I do this:

```
 new Builder3().append3("")...
```

I can access all methods in Builder3, Builder2 and Builder1 - Great.
The issue occurs when I access one of the methods in Builder1 or Builder2, like so:

```
 new Builder3().append1("")...
```

Now, I can only access the methods of Builder1, and I can't get to Builder2 or Builder3.

As I said, I'm sure this has already been answered somewhere else so feel free to point me to any posts about it.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT:**
I should also point out that the methods will all be doing different things. My example makes it seem like they are doing the same thing, from different places.

Comment: To start, you should definitely follow the Java Naming Convention. Class names **always** start with uppercase letter!

Comment: Yea, sorry I normally do that but this was purely an example but I'll make the edit. :P

Answer (score 2):

**[Disclaimer: untested code]**
I would do an abstract base class that defined the base `append*` methods. That ABC would look something like...

```
public abstract class BaseBuilder {

    protected String string = "";

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.string);
    }

    abstract <T extends BaseBuilder> T append1(String string);

    abstract <T extends BaseBuilder> T append2(String string);

    abstract <T extends BaseBuilder> T append3(String string);

}
```

Then, say, for `Builder1`, you could implement `append1(..)`, and throw exceptions for the others.

```
public class Builder1 extends BaseBuilder {
    public <T extends Builder1> T append1(String string) {
        this.string += string;
        return (T)this;
    }

    public <T extends Builder1> T append2(String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("something");
    }

    public <T extends Builder1> T append3(String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("something");
    }
}
```

Same principle for `Builder2`, `Builder3`, and so on

Comment: I understand this approach but it's doing something close to what I'm trying to avoid. The reason I want it to inherit the whole method is because there are a lot of them in the base class and I don't want to have to write them out each time. I also don't want to see the unsupported methods in the IDE when using each builder (The Java Assist / Intellisense thing). Thanks for your opinion, though.

Answer (score 1):

To start off, you should be using a `StringBuilder` for appending text, rather than `String string = new String()`.

`string += string` creates a new `StringBuilder`, which means you're creating one every time your `Builder#append` methods are called.

```
class Builder1 {
    private StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    public Builder1 append1(String text) {
        builder.append(text);
        return this;
    }

    public String build() {
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

---

Next, you should know the `BaseBuilder` interface should only expose behaviors that *all* builders have. You should not be defining `append2` or `append3` to this interface. It should only contain `build`:

```
interface Builder<T> {
    T build();
}
```

---

Finally, for the solution, you should be [decorating](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) to add the functionality.

You would have `Builder1`:

```
class Builder1 implements Builder<String> {
    private StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    public Builder1 append1(String text) {
        builder.append(text);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String build() {
         return string.toString();
    }
}
```

`Builder1` itself expresses how you should continue the decorating for the other builders:

- `Builder1` is composed of it's own builder.
- Calls are delegated to that builder, but the current instances is returned.

`Builder2` would be composed of a `Builder1`:

```
class Builder2 implements Builder<String> {
    private Builder1 builder = new Builder1();

    public Builder2 append(String text) {
        builder.append(text);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder2 append2(String text) {
        //custom behavior
        return this;
    }

    public String build() {
        return builder1.build();
    }
}
```

`Builder3` would be composed of `Builder2`:

```
class Builder3 implements Builder<String> {
    private Builder2 builder = new Builder2();

    public Builder3 append1(String text) {
        builder.append1(text);
        return this;
    }

    public Builder3 append2(String text) {
        builder.append2(text);
        return this;
    }

    // custom append3

    // build() returns builder.build()
}
```

Interfaces exist for interacting: `Builder` defines how *all* builders can be interacted with. If you don't want `Builder1` to have `append3`, then the base interface should not define it.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) definition

> Replace all type parameters in generic types with their bounds or Object if the type parameters are unbounded.

So, after `append1()`, the return type actually is `Builder1`. In order to `append2` or `append3` after `append1`, you can change `<T extends Builder*>` to `<T extends Builder3>` in all the 3 classes.

Answer (score 0):

LOL! I just went through this. What a pain. This works for me. It's located in the base class. However, I pass T back to the base class. You can get the same effect by overriding the method in every child class, with each class returning its own type.

```
/**
 * Return this as type T. This is used by fluent setters and build.
 * 
 * @return
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected T fetchThisAsT() {
    return (T) this;
}
```